# CLOB vs Varchar2 performance in this case?

Tags: oracle, varchar

From java application, I need to store the string which can be more than 4000 characters. I just need to store it. Then person having DB access can query and view it. That column won't be accessed from java application. Also I do not have any requirement to index it.

My understanding is varchar2 is better is in performance than CLOB when we there is a need to access the CLOB datatype or there is need to index it. Is that correct ?

My question - is there any impact in term of performance when we just need to store it and access it in sql developer throigh query ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pre-12c: `varchar2` is limited to 4000 bytes. If you need to store more data in a field, go for `CLOB`.

From 12c: `varchar2` is limited to 4000 bytes, or 32767 bytes after enabling [Extended datatypes](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#BABCIGGA). If you need to store more data in a field, go for `CLOB`. With Extended datatypes, `varchar2` is stored as a LOB internally, where "short" fields go to the table segment, while "long" fields go to the LOB segment.

Both types can be indexed (Oracle Text).

LOBs are designed to be written once, then treat as read-only data. DML operations on existing LOB data typically perform worse than on `varchar2`.

LOBs support deduplication (requires the Advanced Compression option).

Depending on the use-case, `varchar2` can perform better or same.

But based on what you wrote above (read-only data, column is not accessed or searched), `CLOB` should be fine, and you do not need to fiddle with Extended Datatypes or care about the limitations of `varchar2`.

Comment: One drawback to CLOB datatype is some functions won't work with CLOB data types, such as `substr`

Comment: @MarkStewart That is true, but that one happens to be implemented for LOBs: `DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR`.